# Learning to show continuity through open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Below I try showing $h(x) = y, h(y) = x, h(z) = z$ (and its inverse) from $(\mathbb Q, l_x)$ to $(\mathbb Q, l_y)$ is continuous (where $l_p$ is included-point topology).

---

Suppose $O \in l_y$. Then $y \in O$ and so $x \in h^{-1}(O)$ meaning $h^{-1}(O) \in l_x$ implying $h^{-1}(O)$ is open. Thus $h$ is continuous

Define $h^{-1}$ as $h^{-1}(y) = x, h^{-1}(x) = y, h^{-1}(z) = z$. Then $h(h^{-1}(y)) = h(x) = y$ and $h^{-1}(h(y)) = h^{-1}(x) = y$. The other cases are similar and that implies $h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$.

Now assume $U \in l_x$. Then $x \in U$ and so $y \in h^{-1}(U)$ meaning $h^{-1}(U) \in l_y$ implying $h^{-1}(U)$ is open. Thus $h^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

Does the proof above make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is as simple as that: $O \in l_y$ (and WLOG $O \neq \emptyset$) implies $y \in O$ and so $x \in h^{-1}[O]$ as $h(x)=y \in O$ and so $h^{-1}[O] \in l_y$.

Because $h$ is a bijection, to show continuity of the inverse, it's equivalent to show $h$ is open, so take $O \in l_x$ (and WLOG $O \neq \emptyset$) so $x \in O$ and hence $y = h(x) \in h[O]$ and so $h[O] \in l_y$ as required.

If you want to do it via inverse images in the second part, it's clearer to use a different symbol for the inverse, say $g$ and note that $g^{-1}[O] = h[O]$ for open sets in $l_x$ again. Hence the equivalence with openness of the original map.